# how to handle if multiple instances are trying to update a document in Elasticsearch?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, nosql

I am new to Elasticsearch and trying to explore some use case for my business requirement.
What happens if multiple instances try to update a document?
Is there any error handling in place or the document gets locked?
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is using optimistic concurrency control to ensure that an older version of a document never overwrites a newer version.

> When documents are created, updated, or deleted, the new version of the document has to be replicated to other nodes in the cluster. Elasticsearch is also asynchronous and concurrent, meaning that these replication requests are sent in parallel, and may arrive at their destination out of sequence.

For more information you can check Elasticsearch documentation about [optimistic concurrency control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html).